# #array two- dimensions array, there is a undefined index

Tags: php, arrays

My code:

```
<?php

    $country = array(
                 'zh' => array( 'tw' => "Traditional Chinese"),
                 'zh' => array( 'cn' => "Simplified Chinese"),
                 'en' => "English",
                 'jp' => "Japanese"
               );


 echo $country['zh']['tw'];
 echo $country['zh']['cn'];
 echo $country['en'];
 echo $country['jp'];
```

For some reason I get this notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: tw in C:\UniServerZ\www\p7.php on line 3

And I don't see where the bug is in the code?

Comment: You have 2 array occurances with the same key i.e. `$country['zh']` the second occurance of `'zh'` will overwrite the first, therefore there will be no `$country['zh']['tw']` as it does not exist in the second `zh` array

Comment: oh~~ i understand~

Comment: 'zh'=> array('tw'=>"Traditional Chinese", 'cn'=>"Simplified Chinese")

Comment: i succeed !thank u!!

Answer (score 0):

You array should be like :

```
 $country = array('zh'=> array('tw'=>"Traditional Chinese",'cn'=>"Simplified Chinese"),'en' =>"English",'jp' =>"Japanese" );
```

This override the value if zh index

```
'zh'=> array('tw'=>"Traditional Chinese"),'zh'=> array('cn'=>"Simplified Chinese")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this. Avoid over writing of array keys.

```
<?php
 $country = array('zh'=> array('tw'=>"Traditional Chinese",'cn'=>"Simplified Chinese"),'en' =>"English",'jp' =>"Japanese" );
 echo $country['zh']['tw'];
 echo $country['zh']['cn'];
 echo $country['en'];
 echo $country['jp'];
```